# Fetch one result per category from database

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible if I have 6 categories in database to fetch one post from each category and show on page and order by date,desc,asc..

What I mean is I have table `blog`- `id`, `name`, `text`, `category` and multiple posts for each category.

What would be the query to show just one post from every category on the page?

Here is the sample [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e2f3/8) of what I mean. So in this fiddle I want to show 1 result for category 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join to get the one post for each category based on highest id no.

```
SELECT
  b.*
FROM
  blog b
  join (
  select max(id) id,category
    from blog
    group by category
  ) b1
  using(id,category)
ORDER BY b.category
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e2f3/9)

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Just is it possible to order them by date or des/asc?

Comment: @John in outer query you can add your ordering criteria but if you need to select like oldest post per category then you have to change `max(id)` to `min(id)` but this totally based on your criteria to pick which post for each category once this part is done then in outer query you can use your desired order

Comment: I see. Thank's again I will use this approach even if I'm not sure which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return only one row / category:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  blog as b1
where not exists (select 1 from blog as b2
                  where b2.category = b1.category
                    and b2.name < b1.name)
ORDER BY category
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I wonder which method is better.\

Comment: Can't answer that since I'm not a MySQL guy. (Add data, gather statistics, compare execution plans, create index, compare execution plans etc.)